# Special way of returning a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

In a certain function, I used many variables for different usages. I would like to return them, but `return var_1, var_2, ..., var_100, ..., var_n` is clearly not pythonic. I thought creating a dict `kwargs = {"var1": var_1, "var2": var_2, ..., "var_100": var_100, ..., "var_n": var_n}` and returning the dict, but the dict is way too long and it is not pythonic either.

A solution might be to return `dict(var.__name__ : var for var in var_list)` (pseudocode). Clearly, that solution won't work. Is there a way to do that? Is there a way to display the name of a variable, i.e the equivalence of `var.__name__` if I can say?

Comment: If you've got a hundred variables in a function, that's already a problem. You need to refactor your function and/or change how you're organizing your data.

Comment: Needing to *return* every single one of those hundred variables is a bad sign, too. It suggests you may be dividing your code into functions at the wrong points.

Comment: There is not hundred variables, but 10 to 15 var instead. The function is quite light, but I  can't return a dict. It is too heavy. I like return locals() instead even if it will affect the performance

Comment: `locals()` is way more dangerous than it looks. It's got a ton of weird, surprising interactions, including **behaving differently in a debugger**.

Comment: For example, [this script](https://ideone.com/IysIi5) prints an empty dict, but if you uncomment the `pdb.set_trace()` and run it on your own computer, you'll see a completely different thing printed. (I can't really give an online demo of the debugger behavior.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

```
def a_func():
       a = 10
       b = 'a'
       c = 100
       d = 500
       e = False

       return locals()

retval = a_func()
print(retval)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 'a', 'c': 100, 'd': 500, 'e': False}
```

You can also have some filtering (instead of returning all the locals):

```
    ...
    return {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if ...}
```

Comment: This is quite nice and elegant! Thanks! :D

Comment: Is it a good practice to return just the object `locals` instead of `locals()` ? I have the impression it will make the code faster.

Comment: `locals` is a builtin function. You'll need to call it to get the dictionary

Comment: Yeah, I just have to call it when I need it

Comment: @David: If you try that, you'll get the locals of whatever scope you call it in, not the locals of the scope you wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that pretty quickly. So indeed, it is not fine to return just the object haha